# How to selected option enum config in laravel/?

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with build select in Laravel blade and use only two types values from database.

I have column in my migration:

```
 $table->enum('options',['contact','about', 'celebrities', 'introduction']);
```

I have to use it in my blade form to update.

```
<select name="options" id="options" class="form-control">
    @foreach(config('enum.options') as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('options') == $key || $content->options ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you have a file as `config/enum.php` and it has `options` key with related data? Or you want to access available options from migration?

Comment: Yes, I have `config/enum.php`  it has `options` key with related data. I am on edit page of content, It has a select option of `options` . I want to see the saved value in the select option by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673790/how-to-selected-option-enum-config-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment121371578_68673790) you have a `config/enum.php` file.

I assume it is something like this;

```
<?php

return [
    'options' => [
        'contact' => "Contact option name",
        'about'  => "About option name",
        'celebrities' => "Celebrities option name",
        'introduction => "introduction option name",
    ]
];
```

And you have a blade file to show edit form, let's say it `edit.blade.php`

```
<select name="options" id="options" class="form-control">
    @foreach(config('enum.options') as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}" 
        @if($content->options == $key || old('options') == $key) selected @endif
        >
        {{ $value }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Bu keep in mind; if user filled the form and changed `options` select value; then redirected back with errors (for some reason) there will be an `old('options')` value. In this situation if `$content->options` and `old('options')` are different, both of `<option ...>` will have `selected` in them. Browser will show the last item with `selected` as current value. This will not be a perfect solution.

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
@php
    $currentFormOptions = old('options') ? old('options') : $content->options;
@endphp

<select name="options" id="options" class="form-control">
    @foreach(config('enum.options') as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}" 
        @if($currentFormOptions == $key) selected @endif
        >
        {{ $value }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't have a built-in method to retrieve enum options.
Depending on your setup, I'd suggest putting it in an array in your model:

```
class YourModel extends Model {
    public yourEnumOptions = ['contact','about', 'celebrities', 'introduction'];
...
```

For a more dynamic solution (the downside being additional database queries), you could add a method in your model:

```
class YourModel extends Model {
    public function getEnumOptions() {
        $options = DB::selectRaw("show columns from yourTable where field = yourField");
        // Transform the query results string into an array here. 
    }
...
```

Comment: It is not working , I want to selected option default when  I click on edit